# WebView2 on HoloLens2: problem with vcruntime

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, webview2

I am deploying a new component WebView2 on HoloLens2 (ARM64) using Unity and Visual Studio 2022.
It is impossible to initialize a WebView, because of an exception winrt::hresult_error in vcruntime140_app.dll
in function IL2CPP_EXTERN_C IL2CPP_METHOD_ATTR intptr_t WebViewNative_InitializeWebView_m31C05CEDDF260075DD49178C62BFAFE98C714F11 (int32_t ___0_w, int32_t ___1_h, const RuntimeMethod* method);

OS of the device has the following build version: 22621.1113
I am using a compatible Windows SDK with the same version (22621).
How to properly configure the environment to use WebView2 on HoloLens2?
Should I update runtime libraries on HoloLens2? How to do this?

Edit:
For tests I used Unity 2020, 20021, and 2022 (all LTS) and Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. In all cases, the result was the same.
I recreated all steps from the tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/hololens2) and I used a sample project from GitHub - with the same result also.
I read that the change from D3D Project to XAML Project in Unity Build Settings may help, but it did not.

Comment: For this one, can advise if followed these documents?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/hololens2.   Also, can let us know Unity version using for this error?  IL2CPP typically is something we discuss on Unity forums.

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestions. I have edited my post to provide more information.

Comment: I'm also using [the GitHub sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/main/GettingStartedGuides/HoloLens2_GettingStarted) and it works well. You may need to use a clean environment to test again.

Comment: Dear @Jay, could you provide information on which version of VS and Unity are you using, as well as which version of Holographic OS you have installed on your HL2 device? Is it working in both Debug and Release versions?

Comment: I'm using **VS 2022 Version 17.6.5** and **Unity 2021.3.28f1**. For Holographic version, I'm using **Build 22621.1120**. I only tested with **Release** configuration as the doc said, "For Unity projects, choose either **Release** or **Master**".

Comment: Dear @Jay, thank you for your comment. The build number of your OS is higher, maybe this is a significant difference because WebView2 is a relatively new feature. Did you update OS manually? I couldn't update OS to a version newer than 22621.1113 using Windows Update.

Comment: If it helps, the HoloLens OS has released updates (yesterday) since this post.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-23h1---august-2023-update

Comment: Dear @Nathan, thank you. It may help. I will check it out and post the result.